# Compiling less with webpack 4

Tags: webpack, less, webpack-4

How can i compile a `./src/style.less` to `./dist/style.css`?

Here's related part of my `webpack.conf.js`

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {

    module: {
        rules: [

            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    { loader: 'css-loader', options: { url: false, sourceMap: true } },
                    { loader: 'less-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } }
                ],
            },

        ]
    },

    plugins: [

        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "style.css"
        })

    ]

};
```

At moment i get a compiled style.css only if i 
`require('./src/style.less' );` into the index.js

Actually I posted only the settings related to the less compiling.

Comment: Actually, there is no sense to compile less/sass with webapck if you want to "extract css" from the bundle and reference it in html with `link`. No HMR, no tree shaking. So why? Use gulp, keep it simple and optimal.

Comment: I would avoid to use different tools to build my source @RomanPokrovskij

Comment: You will be forced to  use a lot of webpack "loaders". mini-css-extract-plugin is also "a tool".

Comment: Yes i know, but "mini-css-extract-plugin" is a plugin inside Webpack - Gulp is not a plugin. I would like to keep everything within Webpack ecosystem. @RomanPokrovskij

Comment: you can do it without `gulp`, `gulp` there is a sample of common shell. you can chain sass/less and postcss many ways. use that one with which you are common.